# I am trying to send a message to phone using python via way2sms

Tags: python, python-3.x, way2sms

```
import way2sms
import requests

q=way2sms.sms('Arjun','xyz')
q.send(9418403783,'Yo their I am arjun')
n=q.msgSentToday()
q.logout()
```

And I am getting the following error when I run the command. , I have all the required modules installed but facing an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/my dell/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-
>       32/records/smssend.py", line 4, in 
>       q=way2sms.sms('Arjun','M9329G')
>       File "C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
>       32\lib\way2sms.py", line 17, in **init**
>       self.s=requests.Session()           # Session because we want to maintain 
>       the cookies
>       AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: Can you describe how you installed the required modules?

Comment: I installed them manually by downloading them separately and installing  setup.py using cmd..

Comment: Getting warmer, was there a particular URL that you used to download them from?

Comment: Also, do you possible have a file called requests.py somewhere? This may be blocking the import of the requests module.

Answer (score 1):

Sending SMS work properly .Try this .

```
import requests
import json

URL = 'http://www.way2sms.com/api/v1/sendCampaign'
def sendPostRequest(reqUrl):
  req_params = {
  'apikey':'key',
  'secret':'secret',
  'usetype':'stage',
  'phone': 'phone',
  'message':'Hello ',
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the official API of  way2sms from their website. It is a 100% working solution for free test keys. For details, see my answer at-
[Sending SMS using Python via way2sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54524376/way2sms-python-code-not-sending-sms-whereas-posts-returns-success/54590553#54590553)